# Is there a way to call your main component inside of a function in React?

Tags: reactjs

Here is a snippet of my component, SignIn() is the main and isLoggedIn is an event handler. Im wondering if I can re-run SignIn() once I have checked the if statements in isLoggedIn.

```
let loggedIn = false;
let useradmin = "b";
let passadmin = "12345";
const SignIn = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const [pass, setPass] = useState('');

    const isLoggedIn = (user, pass) => {
        if (user === useradmin && pass === passadmin) {
            loggedIn = true;
        } else {
            loggedIn = false;
        }
    }
```

Once I have calculated that loggedIn is true I would like to re-run SignIn() so far I have tried directly calling the function, but that was an "Invalid Hook Call Warning" in jsx. Thank You for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `loggedIn` as a state boolean and change it with the its setter from `isLoggedIn` logic, it will make re-render the component

```
const SignIn = () => {
const [user, setUser] = useState('');
const [pass, setPass] = useState('');
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState('');

const isLoggedIn = (user, pass) => {
    if (user === useradmin && pass === passadmin) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
        loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```